# Starting the node red

Tags: node-red

I would like to retrieve values that I send from a raspberry to my ubuntu PC with the MQTT protocol. For that I want to use node red with influxdb. As a result I installed node red on ubuntu but when I start it I have these errors that I can't fix. I reinstalled several times but to no avail. If you have a solution, I'll take it.
Thank you for your feedback.

IN TERMINAL :

```
opens@opens-maman:~/node-red$ sudo node-red-start
Start Node-RED

Once Node-RED has started, point a browser at http://192.168.0.167:1880
On Pi Node-RED works better with the Firefox or Chrome browser

Use   sudo systemctl enable nodered.service  to autostart Node-RED at every   boot
Use   sudo systemctl disable nodered.service to disable autostart on boot

To find more nodes and example flows - go to http://flows.nodered.org
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib    
/fs/index.js:93
exports.write = function (fd, buffer, ...args) {
                                  ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:6:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Comment: What version of node.js have you got installed? Node-RED requires Node 8.x or later - this error suggests you have an older version installed.

Comment: Oh, I was in version 4.1, something like... I have updated now and it starts correctly.
Thank you very much for your help!